# Bash: multiple files after standard input redirection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdin, io-redirection

Hey I have been researching this for a while and I was wondering if someone can explain the mechanism of this particular feature on the bash shell.

Lets say we have 3 files: `test1.txt`, `test2.txt`, and `test3.txt`.

Contents of each file:

`test1.txt` = "foo"

`test2.txt` = "bar"

`test3.txt` = "hello world"

if we run the following command on bash shell: `cat < test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt` we would get:

```
bar 

hello world
```

My question is why the contents of `test1.txt` ignored in this case, and if anyone has any good sources I can read up on this particular feature.

Comment: The "good source" is the _cat_ man-page: `cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...`, and further down it says: _With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input_. Hence if you had written `cat < test1.txt - test2.txt test3.txt` , you would had gotten the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input redirection is processed before identifying arguments. The command you show, for example, is equivalent to each of

- `< test1.txt cat test2.txt test3.txt`
- `cat test2.txt < test1.txt test3.txt`
- `cat test2.txt test3.txt < test1.txt`

In any case, you are left with `cat`'s standard input being `test1.txt`, and it receiving two command-line arguments `test2.txt` and `test3.txt`.

`cat`, however, only reads from its standard input if it has no arguments naming input files. If you want to read from both standard input and named files, use `-` as the "name" of standard input.

```
# Same result as cat test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
cat - test2.txt test3.txt < test1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `cat` (like most utilities) only reads from standard input if it has no filename arguments. Since you're passing `test2.txt` and `test3.txt` as filenames, it ignores the input redirection.

However, you can use `-` as an argument to mean standard. So you can do:

```
cat - test2.txt test3.txt < test1.txt
```

This isn't very useful when you're redirecting from a file, since you could just provide the filename as a normal argument instead of using redirection, but it can be useful when piping:

```
grep foo test1.txt | cat - test2.txt test3.txt
```